# Pandas dataframe - find last timestamp with valid values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, timestamp

I have a pandas dataframe in which the index is the timestamp and I have a column that contains a value per timestamp, like this:

|  | Values |
| --- | --- |
| timestamp |  |
| `2022-03-17 13:21:00+00:00` | 15.2 |
| `2022-03-22 13:24:00+00:00` | 17.8 |
| `2022-03-27 13:27:00+00:00` | NaN |
| `2022-03-30 13:30:00+00:00` | NaN |

In the column of Values sometimes I get a number and other times I get NaN.

What I am trying to do is to get a new dataframe that contains the values of the last week, for which I am using the next piece of code:

`dataW=data.loc[(pd.Timestamp.utcnow()-pd.Timedelta(days=7)):(pd.Timestamp.utcnow())]`

Which works fine, except if by coincidence the data of the last week is all NaNs: then I get an error.
To solve this, I would like dataW to be a dataframe containing the data of the past seven days from the last day in which the Values is not a NaN. That means that, in the dataframe I wrote as example, instead of getting the data of

`2022-03-30 13:30:00+00:00 - 7 days`

I would like to get the data of

`2022-03-22 13:24:00+00:00 - 7 days`

Does anybody have an idea of how I could do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`last_valid_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.last_valid_index.html):

```
last = data['Values'].last_valid_index()
# or to consider all columns
# last = data.last_valid_index()

data.loc[last-pd.Timedelta(days=7):last]
```

output:

```
                           Values
timestamp                        
2022-03-17 13:21:00+00:00    15.2
2022-03-22 13:24:00+00:00    17.8
```

`last`: `Timestamp('2022-03-22 13:24:00+0000', tz='UTC')`